# Put specific cells on top of the tableView

Tags: swift, xcode

How can i put specific cells to show on top of the tableView? , For example I have 10 cells which 5 of them have red color and other 5 have green and I want to show the top 5 ones with the green colors on top and the other 5 with red below them?

I didn't find any resources so I decided to get advise from the dear SO community.

Code:

```
extension MonitorimiViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return listOfVechicle.count
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "monitorimiCell", for: indexPath) as? MyCustomCell1 else {return UITableViewCell()}
    let currentVechicle = listOfVechicle[indexPath.row]

    cell.veturaOutlet.text = currentVechicle.Plate
    cell.shpejtsiaAktualeOutlet.text = currentVechicle.Speed!
    cell.perditsuarOutlet.text = "\(currentVechicle.LastCommunicationDate!.convertToDisplayForm())"
    cell.pasagjereOutlet.text = "\(currentVechicle.Passengers!) Person/a"
    cell.vozitesiOutlet.text = "\(currentVechicle.Driver!)"

    switch currentVechicle.Status {
    case 1:
        cell.colorsImageView.backgroundColor = .green
    case 2:
        cell.colorsImageView.backgroundColor = .red
    case 3:
        cell.colorsImageView.backgroundColor = .black
    case 4:
        cell.colorsImageView.backgroundColor = .orange
    default: break
    }

    return cell
```

So from the `currentVechicle.Status` I need the case 1 to show on top then the rest.

My data structure coming from the API:

```
struct Vehicles: Codable {

var  IDVehicle: Int?
var  Title: String?
var  RegistrationDate: String?
var  ExpireDate: String?
var  Department: String?
var  Identification: String?
var  Speed: String?
var  Latitude: Double?
var  Longitude: Double?
var  Angle: Int?
var  Status: Int?
var  InputValue: Int?
var  Plate: String?
var  LastCommunicationDate: String?
var  Passengers: Int?
var  Driver: String?

}
```

data coming from api in form of json:

```
{
 "IDVehicle": 0,
 "Title": "Truck",
 "RegistrationDate": "2017-10-26T17:23:20.677",
 "ExpireDate": "2022-10-28T00:00:00",
 "Department": "Transport",
 "Identification": "863286023094252",
 "Speed": "0",
 "Latitude": 80.8769778,
 "Longitude": 70.9877813,
 "Angle": 265,
 "Status": 1,          // I want the cells sorted based on the Status, If status 1 show cells with 1 on top etc.
 "InputValue": 0,
 "Plate": "09 09 KO",
 "LastCommunicationDate": "2021-10-28T13:53:23",
 "Passengers": 0,
 "Driver": "Empty"
}
```

Comment: You can update the data accordingly or you can do something in `cellForRow` method. This is a good hint, you can figure this out from here.

Comment: @Rob thanks for the reply! , I am kinda new to swift and really cant figure it out it will be probably days :( , but I will update the code and if someone can do something little to help :)

Comment: just sort your listOfVechicle collection before reloading the data

Comment: Use `sort()` to put the vehicles with the `status` you want before the other ones. That's the logic. You sort the data(source), not the "cells".

Comment: @Larme hey man thanks for answering my noob questions but I havent used the sort() yet in my experience and it looks kinda tricky with arrays and $0 but ill try to figure it out if I can :).

Comment: And what's the order for the rest? I also suggest that variable starts with a lower case, include all the properties of `Vehicles`.

Comment: @Larme there is no rest mate, also it starts with uppercase because thats how the data come from json from the API, here ill update it how its shown in the api

Comment: You can use Custom CodingKeys, or use `keyDecodingStrategy` from the JSONDecoder. But what's the order of the rest if status is not 1? And why are all your property optional?

Comment: @Larme the rest are for different classes and vc's , also they are optional because the come in different forms i guess :) , and the Status has 4 values, basically if the car i on its Green, if the car has no signal its black, if the car is over the speed limit its 3 red, and yellow if its in service which is nr 4 :)

Comment: Now seeing your data structure, a couple things. Adding a `?` to the end of the type means that it is possible that that variable will never obtain a value. In the case of JSON parsing, you only want to add that question mark when it's possible that that value may not exist in the JSON, or its value is `null`.

Comment: I have edited my code for you.

Answer (score 0):

```swift
struct Vehicles: Codable {
    var Title: String
    var Status: Int // I'm assuming this will never be null in your JSON. Remove all your question marks except for keys that might not have values.
}

var data = [Vehicles(Title: "Honda", Status: 2), Vehicles(Title: "Mazda", Status: 1), Vehicles(Title: "Subaru", Status: 1)]
// You surely keep your data in an Array like this, right? You will need it formatted like this to be able to index it using `IndexPath.row`

data.sort{$0.Status < $1.Status}
// Call this when you're done populating your data.
```

The key thing here is in the .map {} part. $0 means THIS element in the list, much like how `name` in `for name in names {}` would mean the current name in the list. and $1 means the next element in the list. When using `.sort()`, you're comparing one value to the next value repeatedly. In this case, we using the `<` sign because we want the higher values to be further down the list.

Comment: Its going to be really hard to edit your code based on mine :( , But all i am saying is to order based on the switch statement you are seeing, Like basically put the case 1: cells on top :)

Comment: cellForRowAt should not be used for organizing data. That function is called once for each cell you have. It simply does not make sense to organize data once in a function that gets called many many times.

Comment: @ioslifer if you post your data structure I can modify my code for you.

Comment: Yeh done mate, check

Comment: Hey updated it, Also the var  Status: Int? have 4 values which every of those values have a specific color, like 1 has green , 2 has red , 3 has black, 4 has orange :) A pic of a prototype cell on my main VC : https://imgur.com/a/p7bJCR0

Comment: Any reason why naming the method starting with an uppercase? Also, why not use `sort()` directly? Why use `map` instead of `forEach`?

Comment: @Larme well this guy is trying his best from his experience maybe? , is there a shorter way with this sort() ?

Comment: I'm asking questions, don't worry. Everyone can learn, including myself. So I was wondering if the answer could be improved in my opinion, that's all.

Comment: @Larme yep ofc i was not trying to say anything, because both are trying your best to help the community and I love that!

Comment: @Larme. I agree forEach would probably be a better choice. Same results. Didn't cross my mind.

Comment: Well, `map()` is used to transform each elements in an array (in our case an array), into something else and create and another array from that. Here, there is even a "Result of call to 'map' is unused" warning. And since you don't return really anything in the closure, the retrieve value without type annotation throws "inferred to have type '[()]', which may be unexpected" warning, its value in your sample being `[(), ()]`.